# Sparklyr: List contents of directory in R using invoke methods

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Unable to find a sparklyr built in for listing the contents of a directory via Spark, I am attempting to use `invoke`:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn", config=config)
path <- 'gs:// ***path to bucket on google cloud*** '
spath <- sparklyr::invoke_new(sc, 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path', path) 
fs <- sparklyr::invoke(spath, 'getFileSystem')
list <- sparklyr:: invoke(fs, 'listLocatedStatus')
```

```
Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched method found for class org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:134)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66) ...
```

Note: Are there guidelines for reproducible examples with distributed code? I don't know how to make an example others could follow, given I am running against a particular Spark environment.

Comment: _Are there guidelines..._ - [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/6910411)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getFileSystem` method [takes](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#getFileSystem(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)) `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` object as the first argument:

> ```
> public FileSystem getFileSystem(Configuration conf)
>                      throws IOException
> ```
>
> Return the FileSystem that owns this Path.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> `conf` - the configuration to use when resolving the FileSystem

So the code to retrieve `FileSystem` instance should looks more or less like this:

```
# Retrieve Spark's Hadoop configuration
hconf <- sc %>% spark_context() %>% invoke("hadoopConfiguration")
fs <- sparklyr::invoke(spath, 'getFileSystem', hconf)
```

Additionally `listLocatedStatus` [takes either `Path`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listLocatedStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)

> ```
> public org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> listLocatedStatus(Path f)
>                                                                      throws FileNotFoundException,
>                                                                             IOException
> ```

or [`Path` and `PathFilter`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listLocatedStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2C+org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter%29) (note that this implementation is `protected`):

> ```
> public org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> listLocatedStatus(Path f)
>                                                                     throws FileNotFoundException,
>                                                                             IOException
> ```

So if you want to structure your code as shown above you'll have to provide at least a path

```
sparklyr:: invoke(fs, "listLocatedStatus", spath)
```

In practice it might be easier to just get `FileSystem` directly:

```
fs <- invoke_static(sc, "org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem", "get",  hconf)
```

and use `globStatus`

```
lls <- invoke(fs, "globStatus", spath)
```

where `spath` is a path with wildcard, like:

```
sparklyr::invoke_new(sc, 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path', "/some/path/*")
```

The result will be an R `list`, which can be easily iterated:

```
lls  %>%
    purrr::map(function(x) invoke(x, "getPath") %>% invoke("toString"))
```

**Credits**:

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32978688) to [How can one list all csv files in an HDFS location within the Spark Scala shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32771089) by [@jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5373903/jaime)

**Notes**:

- In general, if you interact with non-trivial Java API, it makes much more sense to write your code in Java or Scala, and provide a minimal R interface.
- For interactions with specific file object store it might be easier to use a dedicated package. For Google Cloud Storage you can take a look at [`googleCloudStorageR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleCloudStorageR/vignettes/googleCloudStorageR.html).

Comment: How do I get the contents out of flist ? 
> flist <- sparklyr::invoke(fs, "listLocatedStatus", spath)
> flist
<jobj[71]>
  org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4
  org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4@71ab657

Comment: This is good advice, but, I don't currently know/work in either Java or Scala. Is there a better recommended way for a sparklyr user to list the contents of directories?  I don't find this functionality built-in to sparklyr.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't built-in helper for that. And about your first point - if you don't know Scala or Java, then working with `invoke` directly will be a nightmare. Using JVM language directly is a much better choice - decent IDE can help you will majority of the boilerplate and help you to determine and troubleshoot the errors.

Comment: All this works until I get the resutl of listLocatedStatus.   It's an Environment in R, not an iterable.  It has class attributes 'spark_jobj' 'shell_jobj'

Comment: Only the basic objects (array, primitives, boxed primitives) are converted to equivalent R object. The rest is provided as-is - as handles to java objects. Additionally it looks like `sparklyr` does something unexpected under the hood, trying to access non-public member, though I don't see why it could be the case.